# Getting table schema doesn't seem to work with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQLite.NET to access my databases, and in one particular case, I need to get a table schema because it's application-specific.

I've been looking through the SQLite.NET forum and google, and it seems very straightforward.  If I have a table called MYTABLE, I should be able to do this:

```
DataTable dt = Connection.GetSchema( SQLiteMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, new string[] { null, null, "MYTABLE", null });
```

The problem is that, although I do get a DataTable back, it's got all of the wrong information in it.  Specifically, this is what I get back for the supposed columns of MYTABLE:

- [0] {TABLE_CATALOG} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [1] {TABLE_SCHEMA}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [2] {TABLE_NAME}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [3] {COLUMN_NAME}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [4] {COLUMN_GUID}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [5] {COLUMN_PROPID} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [6] {ORDINAL_POSITION}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [7] {COLUMN_HASDEFAULT} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [8] {COLUMN_DEFAULT}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [9] {COLUMN_FLAGS}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [10]    {IS_NULLABLE}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [11]    {DATA_TYPE} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [12]    {TYPE_GUID} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [13]    {CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [14]    {CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [15]    {NUMERIC_PRECISION} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [16]    {NUMERIC_SCALE} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [17]    {DATETIME_PRECISION}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [18]    {CHARACTER_SET_CATALOG} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [19]    {CHARACTER_SET_SCHEMA}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [20]    {CHARACTER_SET_NAME}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [21]    {COLLATION_CATALOG} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [22]    {COLLATION_SCHEMA}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [23]    {COLLATION_NAME}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [24]    {DOMAIN_CATALOG}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [25]    {DOMAIN_NAME}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [26]    {DESCRIPTION}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [27]    {PRIMARY_KEY}   object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [28]    {EDM_TYPE}  object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [29]    {AUTOINCREMENT} object {System.Data.DataColumn}
- [30]    {UNIQUE}    object {System.Data.DataColumn}

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think that these results are unexpected?  It's one row per column (of the requested table), and each row has all of these aforementioned columns which expand on the various settings of each column (of the requested table).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite possible that `SQLiteConnection.GetSchema` is broken; most programs do not need this functionality.

You can get what you need by executing a [`PRAGMA table_info(MYTABLE)` command](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html); you should get a data reader with one row for each column.

Comment: great tip, thanks a bunch.  It's good to now realize that SQLiteCommands are just passed down to the SQLite engine directly.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to use the [`PRAGMA table_info(tableName)`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) as suggested by [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) to check if a specified column exists in a specified table.

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if the given table contains a column with the given name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tableName">The table in this database to check.</param>
/// <param name="columnName">The column in the given table to look for.</param>
/// <param name="connection">The SQLiteConnection for this database.</param>
/// <returns>True if the given table contains a column with the given name.</returns>
public static bool ColumnExists(string tableName, string columnName, SQLiteConnection connection)
{
    var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")", connection);
    var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())//loop through the various columns and their info
    {
        var value = dr.GetValue(1);//column 1 from the result contains the column names
        if (columnName.Equals(value))
        {
            dr.Close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    dr.Close();
    return false;
}
```