# Reading SQLite table information in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

I would like to read the table and column information in C#.NET Windows application. I know that there is SMO base access for SQL Server. On similar ground is there any API for SQLite?

Comment: Are you searching for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93654/is-there-a-net-c-wrapper-for-sqlite

Comment: @Martin Buberl, that's not the same question... the OP's not looking for an ADO.NET provider, he's asking how to access database metadata

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `GetSchema` method :

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite");
using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=D:\tmp\test.db";
    connection.Open();
    DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
    DataTable columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns");
    tables.Dump();
    columns.Dump();
}
```

`GetSchema` returns a DataTable that contains information about the tables, columns, or whatever you specify. Valid `GetSchema` arguments for SQLite include:

- MetaDataCollections
- DataSourceInformation
- DataTypes
- ReservedWords
- Catalogs
- Columns
- Indexes
- IndexColumns
- Tables
- Views
- ViewColumns
- ForeignKeys
- Triggers

Comment: According to [this stackoverflow post][1], the getSchema does not work for SQLite. I had the same problem and am now using "SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA table_info('tracks')", DB)"


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268986/getting-table-schema-doesnt-seem-to-work-with-system-data-sqlite

Comment: @R-U-Bn, I just tried again, it works fine (at least with the official System.Data.SQLite provider)

Comment: Thx @Thomas but I guess it's specific to some (hard- or soft-) configuration some of us have. (Using provider version 1.0.65)  And I also mentioned it as a backup/quick jump for future users with the same problem. (No discredit meant ;-) )

Comment: @ThomasLevesque how do I figure out what columns are in `DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");` ?

Comment: @BrunoBieri just enumerate `tables.Columns` ;)

Comment: I just tried this on the most recent nuget package and got 'Specified method is not supported.'